# am getting an error unreachable 'console' after 'return'

Tags: javascript, return

please help me figure this out am just too new at this... here is my simple code am learning with that is giving me headache

```
var nameString = function (name) {
   return"Hi, I am" + " " + name;
   console.log ("Hi, I am" + " " + name);
};

nameString(Daniel);
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Or is this a lint or a framework error message? In additon to answers below, if `Daniel` is not a variable name, you need to wrap it within quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming, a `return` statement is used to terminate a function. That mean no instruction will be executed after this statement. So just move your `console.log` before `return` to fix it :

```
var nameString = function (name) {

    console.log ("Hi, I am" + " " + name);
    return "Hi, I am" + " " + name; 

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place "console.log..." before the return instruction.

Like this :

```
var nameString = function (name) {

console.log ("Hi, I am" + " " + name);
return"Hi, I am" + " " + name; 

};

nameString(Daniel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `console.log()` after `return`.

When you return from a function the code after this is not reachable. So in you example `console.log()` will never be executet. Put it bevore the return;

```
 var nameString = function (name) {
   console.log("Hi, I am " + name);
   return "Hi, I am " + name;
 };
```